# Query to return text if row is null from oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Right now I have a query that is giving me a blank space, which is good, but what I really need is something that returns "Empty" if it is null. I've played around with a couple of options and right now this is the best query I have, but I am not sure how to get it to display "EMPTY" if null.

```
SELECT paramOne, paramTwo
FROM tableName
WHERE search_param = 'x' 

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT paramOne, paramTwo
FROM tableName
WHERE search_param = 'x'
);
```

paramOne is number
paramTwo is varchar

the result I am looking for is basically this:

if the row has data it should return 123, Name

if the row has no data it should 000, 'empty'

Comment: What blank space are you talking about? Can you provide sample data of the current table and your expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that paramTwo (the varchar2 one) is not really null, try:

```
SELECT nvl(paramOne, 0), nvl(trim(paramTwo), 'EMPTY')
FROM tableName
WHERE search_param = 'x'
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a little like something that you should consider doing client-side instead of in your query... but you could just hard-code `'EMPTY'` instead of `NULL`:

```
SELECT paramOne, paramTwo
FROM tableName
WHERE search_param = 'x' 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'EMPTY', 'EMPTY'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT paramOne, paramTwo
FROM tableName
WHERE search_param = 'x'
);
```

Comment: I thought about this and tried it, but it returns a blank row if the result is null.

Comment: @mtnwk By blank row, do you mean no row at all, or a row that contains blanks?

Comment: I've used the same approach that you're using for this purpose, but not specifically in Oracle.  I can see no reason why this query should return 0 rows...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn a NULL value into a non-NULL value, use the `NVL` function

```
SELECT NVL( paramOne, 'Empty' ),
       NVL( paramTwo, 'Empty' )
  FROM table_name
 WHERE search_param = 'x';
```

If you are trying to do something else, it would be very helpful if you could post some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: He wants to return `'Empty'` if the first query contains no results... this wouldn't work because there would be no `NULL` values returned to perform `NVL` against.

Comment: I've definitely played around with the NVL a good bit, one thing I notice is that I still get a blank row returned instead of 'Empty'. I should note that paramOne is a number and paramTwo is varchar.

Comment: @mtnwk - Are you trying to transform a query that returns 0 rows of data into a query that returns 1 row of data with hard coded values?  Or are you trying to transform a query that returns 1 row of data with `NULL` values into a query that returns 1 row of data with hard-coded values?  I read your initial post to ask about the former.  Your edit sounds like you may have intended to ask the latter.

Comment: The latter; if it's NULL return something specified; if not null return the data.

Comment: @mtnwk - That's what `NVL` does.  If `NVL` isn't working for you, it would be very helpful if you could post some sample data and the expected output.  Otherwise, it appears that we're having difficulty understanding your requirements.

Comment: OK so paramOne is a number, paramTwo is a varchar (a name).. this what I tried:

    SELECT NVL( paramOne, '0' ),
           NVL( paramTwo, 'Empty' )
    FROM table_Name
    WHERE search_param = 'x';

It works fine if there is data, but if there is no data I just get a blank row. I really want that row to say 'Empty'. What I am doing is running a batch of these SELECT statements so that's why I need it to return something.

Comment: @mtnwk - Now it sounds like you're back to wanting to transform a query that returns 0 rows of data into a query that returns 1 row of data with hard coded values.  I thought you just said that was not what you wanted.  "no data" and "blank row" are very different concepts.  "no data" implies that the query returns 0 rows.  "blank row" implies that the query returns 1 row of data and the values are `NULL`.  Again, it would be very helpful to post a test case.  Post the DDL to create your table, post the DML to populate a couple of rows, post a query that is not returning the data you want.